# How to set the browser's language in Cypress.io (electron/chrome)?

Tags: configuration, internationalization, e2e-testing, cypress, lang

My question is about configuring [Cypress](https://cypress.io) to launch a browser instance in a certain language.

In order to:

- make assertions on localized (i18n) text labels?
- check i18n features (switching between languages)
- bypass issues of Continuous Integration (CI/CD) when, for example, on
  a local computer, the browser default to `fr_FR`, and on the CI/CD VM it defaults to `en_US`?

I tried (without much success):

- using `LANGUAGE=en_US` from the terminal invocation,
- using the Browser's API plugin (see Cypress' [browser launch API documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api#Modify-browser-launch-arguments))

Comment: we tried overwriting navigator.locale with a shim during onBeforeLoad that returns our desired locale, but this doesn't change the locale using in GET requests.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from Gleb Bahmutov:

> you set it during cy.visit using `onBeforeLoad` with something like `Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'language', { value: 'de-GE' })`

src: https://gitter.im/cypress-io/cypress?at=5d61408a07d1ff39f8769545

Comment: Could not make it work, simply ignored my code :


```javascript
    cy.visit('/', {
      onBeforeLoad: (_contentWindow) => {
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'language', { value: 'fr-FR' })
      }
    })
```

Comment: can you try with `cy.visit('/', { onBeforeLoad: (_contentWindow) => { Object.defineProperty(_contentWindow.navigator, 'language', { value: 'fr-FR' }) } })`

Comment: I tried both combinations and couldn't make it work :( any help on this?

Answer (score 8):

To set the language in the browser and also for request, which was what I had to do for my tests, the following worked for me:

```
cy.visit('url', {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, 'language', { value: 'de-DE' });
      Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, 'languages', { value: ['de'] });
      Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, 'accept_languages', { value: ['de'] });
    },
    headers: {
      'Accept-Language': 'de',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

navigator has two lang props:

- language ({ value: 'en-GB'}
- languages(['en-GB'])

navigator.language refers to the first element of navigator.languages
but some libraries check navigator.languages[0] instead of navigator.language, so better if you set both properties

```
onBeforeLoad: (window, ...args) => {
  Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'language', { value: 'en-GB' });
  Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'languages', ['en-GB']);
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/languages

Comment: Note that this implements only *one effect* of changing the browser language - for example, this doesn't change the behavior of `Date.toLocaleString`, and the `Accept-Language` header will not be sent.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In support/index.js

```
Cypress.on('window:before:load', window => {
  Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'language', { value: 'fr' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In our setup we are using Cypress v12.x with 2 different browsers:

- the chrome browser (we use this when running the cypress app interactively `yarn cypress open`)
- the electron browser (is used when running the tests headless on CI `yarn cypress run`)

We found that we need to configure both browsers separately

#### chrome

we use the Cypress Browser Launch API (https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api#Changing-browser-preferences) to customize the chrome configuration.

```
// file cypress.config.js

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("before:browser:launch", (browser, launchOptions) => {
        if (browser.family === "chromium" && browser.name !== "electron") {

          launchOptions.preferences.default.intl = {
            accept_languages: "en-US,en",
            selected_languages: "en-US,en",
          };

          return launchOptions;
        }
      });
    },
  },
});
```

#### electron

we use the environment variable `ELECTRON_EXTRA_LAUNCH_ARGS`  (https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api#Modify-Electron-app-switches) to pass extra args to the electron browser.

```
// file package.json

"scripts": {
    "e2e:run": "ELECTRON_EXTRA_LAUNCH_ARGS=--lang=en yarn cypress run",
    ...
}
```

- electron cli switches: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/command-line-switches#--lang

#### summary

with this configuration the browser is using the specified locale when using the cypress app and also when running the tests on our CI server

Answer (score -1):

Someone got it working with this: (I couldn't)

> Source: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7890#issuecomment-824676390

```js
// cypress/plugins/index.js

on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
  if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
    launchOptions.args.push('--lang=en-GB');
    return launchOptions;
  }
});
```