# Cypress: contains().click() with or statement

Tags: javascript, cypress

the problem is that the Docker image from Cypress sets the browser language to english and some elements on the page are translated to english. It looks like it's a bug in Cypress because the browser in the Docker image, regardless of the set language, translates certain texts into English. even if the set browser language is different.

my local browser language is different than the one in the docker image so some texts are different for me locally than in the dockerimage (english). now i have to build a workaround until cypress manages to fix the bug.

i want cypress to select an element which is selected by a logical or ( `||` ). However it doesn't work because `cypress.contains()` doesn't support this.
For a better illustration here is a simple example of what I mean. Do you have an idea how to implement this?

```
const value1 = data.text_local_language
const value2 = data.text_english

         cy.get("element")
          .contains(value1 || value2)
          .click();
```

Comment: You almost solved it. [Regular Expressions in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) are defined surrounded by slashes, and the _or_ is symbolized by a single pipe: `/value1|value2/` (Note: spaces removed to not match them).

Comment: And since `value1` and `value2` are variables, you need [create a `RegExp` object as pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885855/use-dynamic-variable-string-as-regex-pattern-in-javascript) instead `/../`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression in `contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Regular-Expression)

```js
const value1 = data.text_local_language
const value2 = data.text_english

const regex = new RegExp(`${value1}|${value2}`)  // build regex from variables

cy.get("element")
  .contains(regex)
  .click();
```

The regular expression (inside the slashes) `value1|value2` matches either `value1` or `value2` (*or* is denoted by the pipe-symbol `|`).

Comment: I forgot but you can combine the `.get()` with the `.contains()`. `cy.contains('element', regex)`.

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 4):

There is the [`oneOf`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof) assertion if an exact match is is acceptable.

```js
cy.get('element')
  .should('satisfy', ($el) => {
    expect($el.text()).to.be.oneOf([value1,value2])
  })
  .click()
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Cypress bundles popular *Chai* assertion library. This is why those assertions are not explained in detail in Cypress docs. A link to the docs like [`oneOf`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof) is part of a well-informed answer. It forwards to more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the text contains either text inside a `.then()` command and assert it.

```js
const thisText = 'this'
const thatText = 'that'

cy.get('element')
  .then($el => {
    const text =  $el.text()
    const thisOrThat = text.includes(thisText) || text.includes(thatText)
    expect(thisOrThat, `text contains ${thisText} or ${thatText}`).to.be.true
    cy.wrap($el).click()
  })
```

Comment: until the click it works. i think because the click is outside the method it gives the following error: `cy.click() failed because it requires a DOM element.`

Comment: Yeah, i see the mistake now. Fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

To assert that an element contains **alternative parts** you can use a regular expression (RegExp) inside `contains()`.

### Assert `Contains` RegExp

To build a regex pattern from variables use the constructor `new RegExp` with a string expression.

```
const value1 = 'Hello'
const value2 = 'World'

// simple with plus operator
cy.get("element").contains(new RegExp(value1 + '|' + value2))

// short and expressive with ES6 template literals
cy.get("element").contains(new RegExp(`${value1}|${value2}`))

// for multiple elements use Array.join()
const elements = ['Fire', 'Air', 'Water'];
cy.get("element").contains(new RegExp(elements.join('|'))
```

See also the Cypress Assertions guide on [Text Content](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#Text-Content):

```
// use cy.contains to find an element with its text
// matching the given regular expression
cy.contains('[data-testid="greeting"]', /^Hello/)
```

### Configure browser language in your containerized Cypress

If you want to configure the language used for testing, you could:

- set the [`LANG` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405902/how-to-set-the-locale-inside-a-debian-ubuntu-docker-container) in your docker container, which can then be picked by the browser as system/default locale
- set the [browser preferences](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api#Modify-browser-launch-arguments-preferences-and-extensions) in Cypress's Browser Launch API, which will then be used in the `accept-language` request header

See [Setting the browser language in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671266/setting-the-browser-language-in-cypress)